# How should I modify a CNN to take input of 1 channel images?

Tags: conv-neural-network

I am working on a image compressing problem. The network I am studying is the CompressAI from GitHub: https://github.com/InterDigitalInc/CompressAI.

I want to modify the network to take input images of 1 channel and I do not know where should I get started. I think about other method such as changing 1 channel to 3 channels by duplicating 3 times, but that does not seem to fit the scope of "image compressing". Please, any suggestion where I shoud get start?

Comment: Can you please share the exact model you are trying to use, I will make the changes accordingly and help you out.

Comment: @AzhanMohammed Thank you Azhan in advance. I am using the mbt2018 model. The current dataset I am using is Kodak which is three channel. I want to train the model using a one channel dataset, and eventually can take 1 channel image as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the official repository code [here](https://github.com/InterDigitalInc/CompressAI/blob/master/compressai/zoo/image.py) at line 56 the architecture for mbt2018 model is mentioned as JointAutoregressiveHierarchicalPriors. So the same model's input channels need to be changed. This can be done by changing the definition for the model located [here](https://github.com/InterDigitalInc/CompressAI/blob/f63754c32724c7ee4e7f523729fe387a5c9f86c6/compressai/models/google.py). Change line 411 of the file from:

```py
conv(3, N, kernel_size=5, stride=2),
```

to

```py
conv(1, N, kernel_size=5, stride=2),
```

This ensures that the model now works for single channel images.

Comment: Many many many thanks!!! If you have more patience, could you please help me with another problem? I want to input images with 1 channel and 12 bits on every pixel. The current situation is 8 bits. So when To_Tensor normalizing the vector of each pixel, some infomation lost. Could you please help me with how to change the To_Tensor?

Comment: @leeLin I would need some additional information to help you, can you share the input image type, and the transforms function you are using? I am not able to understand your problem clearly.